# Files, Topics and Milestone Tracker console components are missing

Tags: service-cloud-console

If you edit Case page layout, you can define Custom Console Components (not all of which are actually custom). I am able to add Knowledge One component, but Files (unless I add them as related list), Milestone Tracker and Topics are missing, even after enabling Entitlement Management and Topics.

Anything I am missing?

[image: custom console components options]

Comment: A couple thoughts: Is Topics enabled for Case? In setup tree under Customize->Topics->Topics for Objects you can check if Case is enabled. For the milestone issue is the FLS for the entitlement fields on Case object set properly? I believe they're hidden by default which may be why you can't add it to the case layout.

Comment: Topics are enabled for case. Did it work for you? I will check the FLS for the entitlement fields, thank you.

Comment: Yeah, adding the Topics component worked for me in my test org once I turned Topics on. I don't have entitlements set up so I wasn't able to test that.

Answer (score 0):

For adding the Milestone Tracker to the custom console components, have you added the Case Milestones related list to the page layout?

In my case-feed layouts, I've added the Milestone Tracker and Files components to the UI via the Feed View link in the page-layout editing screen, rather than as custom console components.